# Scala: Check for null for List

Tags: java, scala

I am new to Scala after coding for 10 years in Java. Still getting hold of functional programming.
How can I check if the list is null or not?
Code looks something like this:

```
val filterList = filters.map { filter =>
        //some operations
      }
```

//Other function

```
filterList.foldLeft(true)((result1, result2) => {
```

Now if `filters` is null then `filterList` is going to be null too.

Comment: If `filters` is `null`, calling `filters.map` will throw an exception, so `filterList` won't even matter. If `filters` is a `List`, however, no reasonable program should allow it to be `null` in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

If `filters` is `null` (which is different from being empty) then that indicates some pretty careless programing, but it can be handled.

```
val filterList = Option(filters).map(_.map { ...
```

Now `filterList` is of type `Option[X]` where `X` is the collection type for `filters`. Note the 1st `map` is to unwrap the `Option` and the 2nd `map` maps over the collection, except if `filters` was `null`, then the 2nd `map` is never invoked and the whole result is `None`.

Comment: Note that [Option#apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Option$@apply[A](x:A):Option[A]) is the method that's being used here. Its docs say: `"An Option factory which creates Some(x) if the argument is not null, and None if it is null.
"`

Answer (score 2):

`val filterList = if(filters == null) Seq.empty[SomeType] else filters.map {...}`

However, you should try to make sure it never gets to be null, because we try to avoid null variables in Scala. Use the Option[T] type, or empty collections instead